# combining 3 webviews into one view

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to display 3 different websites one after another by creating their respective webviews in android and combine all 3 child views into single parent view. I want to see each view by applying fling gesture, but I am having problem in extending the View class, to hold 3 web views, Can anybody throw some light on this?

If you have any other suggestions you are free to pour in. Right now I am able to display only one website, I want two more to follow this. Since the web result are basically the browser output, we cant fling upon a browser so how should I go ahead with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt my answer, but can you use ViewFlipper and put all these WebViews inside it?

I doubt my answer, since ViewFlipper takes horizontal touch actions, which are also listened to by the WebView.

Just try that out. or if you could set horizontal scrolling into your webview to off position, things might work!

As far as fling actions are concerned, I guess you can tweak the ViewFlipper to flip between views when the device is flinged.